# Request airdrop doesn't work

Tags: anchor, rust, airdrop

Tried to request airdrop:

```
   const wallet = useAnchorWallet();
   const anchorProvider = new AnchorProvider(new 
     Connection(cluster.endpoint), wallet, {
      "preflightCommitment": "processed",
      "commitment": "processed"
     });

    anchorProvider.connection.requestAirdrop(
      pda,
      1 * anchor.web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
    );
```

But failed:
[image]

Any solutions?

[image]

Comment: share the github code, I will be happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me earlier today. Try out the Thirdweb Solana faucet - just put in address for the 1 Sol air drop https://thirdweb.com/faucet/solana

Answer (score 0):

airdropping tokens in Solana is different than Ethereum. each time Solana airdrops, it has to create a token account which is extra work. so solana devnet is sometimes goes down.